# Ubuntu 16.10 + MS Exchange

Tags: linux, ubuntu, evolution

Не могу найти внятного решения для подключения MS Exchange в Ubuntu 16.10. Смотрю в сторону Evolution но там отсутствует возможность типа подключения MAPI. Установка пакета evolution-mapi результата не дало.

Имеется outlook web app owa, через сайт зайти можно без проблем, но нужен почтовик. Пробую пока настроить отдельный OWA сервер, но без результатно.

Comment: Evolution умеет OWA, плагин называется `evolution-ews`.

Comment: @0andriy установил плагин, однако не пойму как им воспользоваться. При заполнении URL https://owa.unitedmeat.ru/owa/ меняет на https://ci-mailbase.clasinvest.local/EWS/Exchange.asmx и не соединяет с почтой